# Does python have an equivalent to Java's hashUnencodedChars?

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, hash

I am hashing a string in Java with `Hashing.sha256().hashUnencodedChars(data)` and I need to recreate this same hash in Python.

The current hash I am using for Python is `hashlib.sha256(data.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()`

These do not create the same hash. As the Java method implies, it is not encoding the value before it hashes. Can I achieve the same functionality in Python?